# dpi value of default "large", "medium" and "small" text views android

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

Does the documentation ( or anyone) talks about the dpi values of the default

- Large TextView {`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`}
- Medium TextView {`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`}
- Small TextView        { `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`}

widgets in the SDK ?

[image: The Large, medium, small and regular text views]

To put it in another way, can we replicate the appearance of these text views without using the `android:textAppearance` attribute?

Comment: If you are using an intelliJ product such as Android Studio you will be able to view the documentation whenever you press F1 on the `android:textAppearanceValue` this will give you the size in sp/dp of the value.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

See in the android sdk directory.

In `\platforms\android-X\data\res\values\themes.xml`:

```
    <item name="textAppearanceLarge">@android:style/TextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceMedium">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@android:style/TextAppearance.Small</item>
```

In `\platforms\android-X\data\res\values\styles.xml`:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

`TextAppearance.Large` means style is inheriting from `TextAppearance` style, you have to trace it also if you want to see full definition of a style.

Link: http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Answer (score 19):

> To put it in another way, can we replicate the appearance of these text views without using the android:textAppearance attribute?

Like [biegleux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300995/biegleux) already said:

- *small* represents 14sp
- *medium* represents 18sp
- *large* represents 22sp

If you want to use the *small*, *medium* or *large* value on any text in your Android app, you can just create a `dimens.xml` file in your `values` folder and define the text size there with the following 3 lines:

```
<dimen name="text_size_small">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_medium">18sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_large">22sp</dimen>
```

Here is an example for a TextView with *large* text from the `dimens.xml` file:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/hello_world"
  android:text="hello world"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Programmatically, you could use:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```