# Difference between "@" and "?" on concrete example?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I know the definition of difference between XML attribute starting with `@` and `?`. The first one refers to global style attribute, while the second one applies to the same attribute within the concrete style. In short.

However, I am still not firm on when to use one or another qualifier. Namely, what is the difference between

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
```

This is the same attribute, right?!

Then, why there is

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

and **there is not** anything like

```
android:textColor="?android:color/black" (or similar variance)
```

Lastly, is the usage of `?` the same as using an attribute from `DeviceDefault` group?

I hope someone will be able to clarify these things for me. I am sure I am over-complicating things and that is why I need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`?android` = **this is used for access a style attribute that's defined in a style theme**

**info:**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

`@android` = **this is used for resources that are defined in your project or the Android framework.**

**eg:**

`android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` this is a style which is in current theme.

`android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"` this is a style which is inbuilt style of android.. no doubt these might be same..

**check this link:**

[dpi value of default "large", "medium" and "small" text views android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590538/dpi-value-of-default-large-medium-and-small-text-views-android)

Comment: But "style theme" can be either custom (my) or system (like Holo)? So using `?` on Holo theme would access attributes that only exist in the Holo Theme?

Comment: I could not understand your last point. Can you clarify? Maybe on example? I posted a few examples

Answer (score 0):

This is also available

android:textColor="?android:color/black"

Set this to some xml component and you can navigate to that component from xml, which will be inside your

/sdk/platforms/android-#/data/res/values/colors.xml